# Load tabs remotely using bootstrap 3 with ID

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to load a tab remotely using bootstrap 3? And if so, is it possible to load only a certain part of a website remotely (via ID tag)? If so, how can this be done with bootstrap 3 tabs? I have tried several methods and they simply do NOT work. Thank you!

Here's what I got so far. When I clicked the ajax tab, it just loads on a new page. I want it to load a certain content from that page. Basically, what im trying to do is load contents inside #tabkarma from the remote page, onto the current webpage via tabs. But so far, its not working.

JS

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About Me</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#content" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Content</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#activity" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Activity</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#followers" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Followers</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/b/reputation.php?uid=4" data-target="#tabkarma" data-toggle="tabajax" id="tabkarma">Karma</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#achievements" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Achievements</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="about">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="content">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="activity">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="followers">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabkarma">Loading</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="achievements">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: check this bootply http://www.bootply.com/63891

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note, remove the `id="tabkarma"` from the link because it is conflicting with the actual tab.

Now if you only want to load a specific portion from a page you should use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). From the docs:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

So the script would look like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    //Add the selector of the element you want to fetch from the external page to the url (with a blank space in between)
    $(targ).load(loadurl + " #loadthis", function () {
        $this.tab('show');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/qgxmvgwg/1/)**

Note that this will make an ajax call each time the link is clicked, you may want to add a check to only do this once.

Comment: I am trying to use this method, but for some reason when I click on the tab, it just loads a new page. Here's the link for example: http://1shotgg.com/b/member.php?action=profile&uid=1

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: @PlusOne if you click on the error shown in the console it will take you to the actual line the problem is (in chrome at least), look at the source and you'll see this `var  = $(this)` instead of this `var $this = $(this)`

Comment: Alright, I managed to rename the variable (did it in jfiddle, and the workedworked) but it is still not working on the website.

Comment: @PlusOne the problem is that in your page you're including the script in the `<head>` so you need to wrap it inside a [`$(document).ready();`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler

Comment: Solved. Thank you, you are a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

How I would approach this is via hidden DOM elements.

For example, within the target site, there is something along the line of

```
<div id="tabkarma"></div>
```

And within that is the content you want. You can load that via jQuery's ajax, so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://targetsite.com/whatever",
    data:{}
}).done(function(msg){
    $("#hiddendiv").html(msg);
});
```

The trick with this is that `#hiddendiv` refers to some div with styling similar to `display: none;`. This forces the browser to construct DOM level objects for your loaded content, but not to display it. Then, it's a simple jQuery call to load your target content into your actual tab:

```
$("#tabajax").html($("#tabkarma").html());
```

Which just says "take all the HTML code inside of `#tabkarma` and put it into `#tabajax`".

One thing to note: most servers do not support cross origin AJAX requests: aka, if you call this code from `mycoolurl.com` and it references code at `somethingcool.com`, it will be blocked by default, but there are ways of configuring your web server to not block this, or just by using something like http://www.whateverorigin.org/.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it...

**HTML**

```
<div role="tabpanel">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"> <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-url="url-to-home"><!-- make sure you update the data-url for this page -->
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-url="url-to-profile"><!-- make sure you update the data-url for this page -->
            Profile</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.nav a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $(href).load(url + " #tabkarma", function (result) {
        pane.tab('show');
    });
});
```